# While loop with delay makes JFrame unresponsive

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, jframe

So, my JFrame becomes unresponsive when I run this code. I managed to trace it back to the while loop under gameLoop(). Regardless of using delay(1000/FRAMERATE) which calls Thread.sleep() within it, it will not allow the Key or Mouse Listeners to do their job.

Full code below, problem exists in gameLoop()

```
package me.LemmingsGame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseListener{

    private World wrld;//reference to current world
    private WorldFile loader=null;//world data

    private int gateCounter;

    private int width,height; //width and height of level

    private int mx,my;

    private int tool = Lemming.CLIMB;
    private Image dbImage; private Graphics dbg; //backbuffer  
    private Image [] sprites;//all images used in game

    private Lemming[] lemmings; //array of all Lemmings in level
    private int nextLem;//next Lemming to be received from Gate class

    private int running;//state of game
    private static final int FRAMERATE=180;//assigned framerate

    public Game(WorldFile loader){
        super("Lemmings");
        setLocation(50,40);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        width=3+loader.x*10;height=29+loader.y*10;
        loadImages();
        lemmings=new Lemming[loader.noLemmings*loader.gates().length];
        setSize(width,height);
        setVisible(true);   
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.loader=loader;
        running=2;
        dbImage= createImage(width,height);
        dbg=dbImage.getGraphics();
        wrld=new World(loader,createImage(width,height), sprites, this);
        gameLoop();
    }
    public void loadImages(){
        sprites=new Image[2];
        sprites[0]=new ImageIcon("Resources/toolbar.png").getImage();
        sprites[1]=new ImageIcon("Resources/selector.png").getImage();
    }
    public static void delay(long len){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(len);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void moveLemmings(){
        if(nextLem>0)
            for(int i = 0;i<nextLem;i++)
                lemmings[i].cycle();
    }
    public void gameLoop(){

        wrld.openGates();
        while(running>0){
            delay(1000/FRAMERATE);
            if(running==2){
                gateCounter++;
                if(gateCounter>FRAMERATE*2){
                    wrld.cycleGates();
                    gateCounter=0;
                }
                moveLemmings();
                if(nextLem>0)
                    wrld.checkPositions(lemmings,nextLem);
            }
            repaint();
            //paint(getGraphics());
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(wrld!=null){
            dbg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            dbg.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            wrld.draw(dbg);
            if(nextLem>0)
                for(int i=0;i<nextLem;i++){
                    lemmings[i].draw(dbg);
                }
            dbg.drawImage(sprites[0],0,0,null);
            dbg.drawImage(sprites[1],tool-3*39,0,null);
            g.drawImage(dbImage,3,29,this);
        }
    }
    public void addLemming(Lemming lemmy) {
        lemmings[nextLem]=lemmy;
        lemmy.spawn();
        nextLem++;
    }
    public void goal(){
        running=0;
        dispose();
        new Menu();
    }
    public void fail(){
        running=0;
        dispose();
        new Menu();
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boop");
        mx=e.getX();
        my=e.getY();
        if(my<40)
            if(mx<40)
                tool=Lemming.CLIMB;
            else if(mx>39&&mx<=39*2)
                tool=Lemming.CHUTE;

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boop2");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

If it matters the program begins here and goes to the Game class

```
package me.LemmingsGame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1448646591011984524L;
    private JComboBox worldList;
    private JButton launch, worldEditor;
    private String [] worldPaths;
    private String [] worldNames;
    private int currentWorld;
    public Menu(){
        super("Lemmings! By: Jordan and Seth");
        this.setLocation(new Point(550,400));
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        File listDir[] = new File("./Worlds").listFiles();
        int x=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listDir.length; i++) 
            if (listDir[i].isDirectory()) 
                   x++;
        worldPaths=new String[x];
        worldNames=new String[x];
        x=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listDir.length; i++) 
            if (listDir[i].isDirectory()){ 
                    worldPaths[x]=listDir[i].getPath().substring(2);    
                    worldNames[x]=worldPaths[x].substring(7);
                    x++;
            }
        worldList=new JComboBox(worldNames);
        worldList.addActionListener(this);
        worldEditor=new JButton("Open World Editor");
        worldEditor.addActionListener(this);
        launch = new JButton("Play");
        launch.addActionListener(this);
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cp.add(worldEditor);
        cp.add(worldList);
        cp.add(launch);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==worldEditor){
            dispose();
            new MapEditor();
        }else if(e.getSource()==launch){
            dispose();
            try {
                new Game(new WorldFile(worldPaths[currentWorld]));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(e.getSource()==worldList){
            currentWorld=worldList.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Menu();
    }
}
```

Probably irrelevant, but here's a plug to the github repo https://github.com/cybnetsurfe3011/Lemmings-Computer-Science/

Comment: *"`Game extends JFrame` ... `Menu extends JFrame`"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing `Thread.sleep()` in your main thread which in this case is the EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread). This thread is responsible for painting your graphics and listening to events. By doing `Thread.sleep()` you are essentially pausing it, thus not allowing it to do it's job.

It seems that you want to refresh your GUI at intervals (at least that is what I am guessing). If this is the case, you will need to move your logic to a new separate thread and then, call what ever update methods you will need from the thread you will have spawned off. To make changes visible, you will need to call the event dispatcher thread again by using the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.